# Managing "scenes".....specifically, Pro Tools workflow

Tags: pro-tools, sound-design, session-organization

I'm currently working on a throwback radio drama (no image involved).  It's not long, however, production value is going to be very high.  There is a fairly significant amount of foley/sound design being applied throughout.

Curious, what can you tell me about track management and scene management in Pro Tools.  I'm working the project scene by scene - learning the workflow as I go.  For tracks, I currently have 4-5 foley tracks per character, 10-15 stereo and mono tracks for layering fx, and 5-8 tracks dedicated to layering the scene ambiance (all this is in addition to the primary and secondary dialog tracks).    I don't have a specific issue with the track workflow, I'm quite interested to get your input on timeline management.

Region groups? Track Groups? Aux sends? Edit/Timecode Lock?

What can I learn....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd set up submasters for your dialogue, FX, Foley, music and ambience tracks. Example, hard bus (on the output, as opposed to on a send) your dialogue tracks to an aux & solo safe it. Then, hard bus all the submasters to a final printmaster aux (or a printmaster audio track if you're using HD.)

As far as splitting for scenes, it ultimately just needs to be manageable. With 4-5 tracks of Foley per character, you might want to pre-dub this stuff together. Mix each track you need so that you've got a solid sounding Foley mix for each character, and then either use a mix/edit group or do a layback of that mix.

If you stagger by scene (e.g. scene 1 FX uses FX 1-4, scene 2 uses FX 5-8, etc.) your life will be much easier.

I normally use time lock on my regions, primarily with dialogue when sync is crucial.

Region groups are useful for a lot of things, mostly editing, but also if you've got some sort of layered effect that you need to use a bunch of, like a gunshot or monster footstep.

Hope that helped a bit! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  No, that is exactly the type of input I wanted to hear....I'm using most of the described techniques already (hard bussing, print master, and time lock, etc), but the Foley layback and fx staggering hadn't occurred to me!  Thanks again!